# Why do we need inner size loop in case of BFS when we have queue which processes in FIFO basis?

Tags: algorithm

This is the algorithmic template for BFS. In this we have a while loop which checks emptiness of queue. My question is why we need inner for loop which loops till size of queue. Whereas when queue processes elements in FIFO manner.

```
int BFS(Node root, Node target) {
    Queue<Node> queue;  // store all nodes which are waiting to be processed
    int step = 0;       // number of steps neeeded from root to current node
    // initialize
    add root to queue;
    // BFS
    while (queue is not empty) {
        step = step + 1;
        // iterate the nodes which are already in the queue
        int size = queue.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            Node cur = the first node in queue;
            return step if cur is target;
            for (Node next : the neighbors of cur) {
                add next to queue;
            }
            remove the first node from queue;
        }
    }
    return -1;          // there is no path from root to target
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, I spent a lot of time thinking about it.
I couldn't understand the reason for the loop as its not in the [standard BFS algorithm](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/graphs.pdf)

I figured out the connection between the loop and the `Queue`.
Without the inner for loop, the outer `while` loop and the `Queue` just have to do more work.

Implementation-wise, you have to store the `step` in the `Queue`, along with the curr / root.
You can do this by enhancing the `Node` class to store the step as well.
Next `step` value doesn't need to be calculated, as we stored it in the neighbors, we can just fetch the stored value to check if we've reached the target.

```
int BFS(Node root, Node target) {

    Queue<Node> queue;  // store all nodes which are waiting to be processed
    int step = 0;       // number of steps needed from root to current node

    // initialize
    add {root, step} to queue;

    // BFS
    while (queue is not empty) {

        Node {cur, storedStep} = remove the first node in queue;
        step = storedStep;            
        
        return step if cur is target;
                  
         // hopefully these are all unvisited 
        for (Node next : the neighbors of cur) { 
        
            //these elements are part of the next level
            add {next, step + 1} to queue;      
            
        }
    }
    return -1;          // there is no path from root to target
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because otherwise `step` will not be correct.

Comment: Ok, So to process levels or adjacent elements, we need this loop. Thanks